# Joining sql tables with no common columns without ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have my data in a form of 2 coma separated strings

```
DECLARE @ids nvarchar(max) = '1,2,3'
DECLARE @guids nvarchar(max) = 
'0000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000,
`0000000-0022-0000-0000-000000000000`,
`0000000-0013-0000-0000-000000000000'`
```

I need them in a table as separate columns based on their position in the string

```
Table1
| Id | Guid                                |
| 1  | 0000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000 |
| 2  | 0000000-0022-0000-0000-000000000000 |
| 3  | 0000000-0013-0000-0000-000000000000 |
```

I can split both strings into separate tables by using

```
DECLARE @split_ids
(value nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@ids, ',' ,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

INSERT INTO @split_ids(Value)
SELECT r.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)
```

I've tried

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) as seqnum
  from cte_Ids t1
 ) t1 FULL OUTER  JOIN
 (SELECT t2.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Value]) as seqnum
  from cte_barcodes t2
 ) t2
 ON t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

But that orders the tables by `Value` and my data is random and can't be ordered.

Is there a way of joining tables based on their row numbers without ordering them first?

Or is there another way of inserting data from a string to a table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split multiple comma separated columns into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50482648/split-multiple-comma-separated-columns-into-rows)

Comment: Use `over (order by select 1)` or some other constant - it may retain orignal order.

Comment: The thing you need is a splitter that observes ordinal positions, such as [delimitedsplit8k_Lead](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)

Comment: @Arvo I get:  `Windowed functions, aggregates and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions. ` error with that

Comment: Maybe `(order by (select 1))` then - this all is just idea for further research, not an answer :)

Comment: @Arvo that does indeed work perfectly. If you put that as an answer all mark as correct. Thank you

Comment: _But that orders the tables by Value and my data is random and can't be ordered._ Nope. You fall under the common illusion that rows in a table have some definite order. A resultset also has no particular order without an order by clause. Selecting rows without an order by clause means the engine is free to return them in **ANY** order. If you want a "random" order, there are ways to do that. But there is no way to write a query that returns rows in the order stored on disk that you appear to assume is "random".

Comment: @SMor Yeah random might not have been a correct word for it. What I meant is that my data has a specific order in the strings and I need to keep that order and I cant order it in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need row numbering over initial order, this means that you should use some constant expression in window function `order_by` clause.
SQL server does not allow use constants directly, but `over(order_by (select 1))` is allowed:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
 FROM (SELECT t1.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) as seqnum
  from cte_Ids t1
 ) t1 FULL OUTER  JOIN
 (SELECT t2.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (select 1)) as seqnum
  from cte_barcodes t2
 ) t2
 ON t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Note that this doesn't guarantee initial order (it will be unspecified), but often it behaves correctly :)

Comment: `(ORDER BY (select 1))` Warning - this is logical nonsense. It tells the engine to order them any way it wants and that order can change from execution to execution. It is also not "random" if that is truly the goal. On a lightly loaded machine, multiple executions might result in the same output - which by definition is not random.

Comment: @SMor Absolutely correct :) Gordon solution is likely correct one; my "no-order" could be used in ad-hoc queries, when one can see the result immediately; such approach is not recommended for production systems! If it does not break today, it will break after sql upgrade or something.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to split and/or insert the input data into separate tables. In this situation you simply need to parse the input strings and get the substrings and their ordinal positions (an XML-based approach or a splitter function are possible solutions).

But if you use SQL Server 2016+, a JSON-based approach is also an option. The idea is to transform the strings into valid JSON arrays (`1,2,3` into `[1,2,3]`), parse the arrays with `OPENJSON()` and join the tables returned from `OPENJSON()` calls. As is [explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-value) in the documentation, the columns that `OPENJSON()` function returns (when the default schema is used) are `key`, `value` and `type` and in case of JSON array, the `key` column holds the index of the element in the specified array.

```
DECLARE @ids nvarchar(max) = N'1,2,3'
DECLARE @guids nvarchar(max) =  N'0000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000,0000000-0022-0000-0000-000000000000,0000000-0013-0000-0000-000000000000'

SELECT j1.[value] AS Id, j2.[value] AS Guid
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', @ids, ']')) j1
JOIN OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(@guids, ',', '","'), '"]')) j2 ON j1.[key] = j2.[key]
```

Result:

```
Id  Guid
1   0000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000
2   0000000-0022-0000-0000-000000000000
3   0000000-0013-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One of solutions is to parse your comma separated values in a loop (using `WHILE`) from both variables. Then you could insert those extracted in the same iteration values at once as one row to a table.

Answer (score 0):

One solution uses recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select cast(null as nvarchar(max)) as id, cast(null as nvarchar(max)) as guid, @ids + ',' as rest_ids, @guids + ',' as rest_guids, 0 as lev
      union all
      select left(rest_ids, charindex(',', rest_ids) - 1),
            left(rest_guids, charindex(',', rest_guids) - 1),
             stuff(rest_ids, 1,  charindex(',', rest_ids), ''),
             stuff(rest_guids, 1,  charindex(',', rest_guids), ''),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest_ids <> ''
     )
select id, guid
from cte
where lev > 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef97b0e7c0da3e4493d529d3e934becb) is a db<>fiddle.